# Proper way to create an aside/sidebar environment

Tags: columns, cv, layout, sidebar

So this is an issue I've had for awhile when learning about LaTeX and using it to create my resume/cv.

When I refer to a sidebar, I'm mean more like how it is done in these templates:

- [Example 1](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv)
- [Example 2](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/wenneker-resume-cv)
- [Example 3](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/friggeri-cv-template/hmnchbfmjgqh)

Simply just a clear area with text that is separate from the main content.

One way I thought to do it was use what the 3rd example uses, with is like so

```
\newenvironment{sidebar}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\color{darker} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \let\section\oldsection
}
```

However the third example redefines `section` which, while I don't know a lot about LaTeX, I don't particularly like. And as [answers in this post suggest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518719/subsection-throws-latex-error-theres-no-line-here-to-end) that's not a good idea.

So, my question is:

What is the most straightforward way to create an aside/sidebar like environment? I've seen people suggest `mdframed` and `wrapfig`, the Friggeri-CV template uses `textpos`, but I would like a definitive way to get what the templates I've given do that aren't redefining LaTeX's main commands.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the examples in `moderncv`.

Comment: @Bernard hey Bernard, what exactly am I looking for in moderncv?

Comment: They seem to use systematically what you call an aside bar. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Well yes, but I'm not sure where I'd find the environment that is used to define that. I could instead just create an environment that uses `\vspace{6pt}` and center the text, and place that first in my document so it's on the left side of my document.